# Prevent clang-tidy from running on generated files

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers, clang-tidy

We have a project that includes protobuf files that get pre-compiled into C++ files.  Unfortunately, those files (like the other source files in the project) get checked by clang-tidy and generate a large number of warnings.

The relevant top-level `CMakeLists.txt` statements are:

```
# For all targets
set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY ${CLANG_TIDY_EXECUTABLE}; --header-filter=.)

# Generated protobufs
include_directories(SYSTEM ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/grpc_interface)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    # ...
    grpc_services
)
```

And the `grpc_interface/CMakeLists.txt` contains:

```
project(grpc_services)

set(PROTO_IMPORT_DIRS
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/protocols/protobuf/
)

set(PROTOS
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/protocols/protobuf/test_message.proto
)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${PROTOS})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
        protobuf::libprotobuf
        gRPC::grpc++
)

get_target_property(GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN gRPC::grpc_cpp_plugin LOCATION)

protobuf_generate(
    TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}
    IMPORT_DIRS ${PROTO_IMPORT_DIRS}
    LANGUAGE cpp
)

protobuf_generate(
    TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}
    IMPORT_DIRS ${PROTO_IMPORT_DIRS}
    LANGUAGE grpc
    GENERATE_EXTENSIONS .grpc.pb.h .grpc.pb.cc
    PLUGIN "protoc-gen-grpc=${GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN}"
)
```

One option is to copy a `.clang-tidy` file that disables all warnings into the `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/grpc_interface` directory, but I think that that would still incur the time penalty of clang-tidy parsing those files.

The "grpc_services" target only contains generated files.

Is there a better way of disabling clang-tidy processing in just that folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the "grpc_services" target only contains generated files, you can just set [the `CXX_CLANG_TIDY` target property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LANG_CLANG_TIDY.html) on that target to be nothing.